# Grails view all output from tests (including logger output)

Tags: grails

I'm running my grails tests like so:

```
 grails test-app -echoOut -echoErr :unit <test_class>
```

and as expected this echos any stdout and stderr to terminal. Is there a way to get the log messages to appear on stdout as well? I guess this could be handled in one of two ways:

1. configure logger to output to stdout.
2. grails test-app is able to intercept logging messages and display them in stdout stream.

Can anyone suggest which of these two methods is 'best', i would prefer to use method 2 if this is possible, any examples of how to set this up?

This has also been queried in this question comment [grails test-app to output to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217873/grails-test-app-to-output-to-console#comment6647007_2219029)

Thanks!