# How to redirect log messages to test reports in Grails 2.4.x+?

Tags: grails

I've recently updated a Grails 2.2 project to 2.4.4 and I've found that when running 'grails test-app' all log messages (info, debug, error, etc.) are now output to the console as opposed to the generated test reports.

Previously all log output would be appended to the body of the test report and I would only receive the result of the test in the console.  Now the default behavior is to print the log messages into the console making the output difficult to parse when running hundreds of tests.

```
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Running 2 unit tests... 1 of 2
2015-02-05 12:16:53,965 [main] INFO  testapp.HelloController  - Hello World Log
| Completed 1 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 5s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in /Users/pk/workspace/testapp/target/test-reports
```

I've confirmed this is the default behavior of Grails 2.4.4 (and likely from sometime prior to that).  Interestingly, messages printed directly to stdout via the 'println' command appear in the log file.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior to print all log output to the test report and not to the console?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Can you show us your `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` file?

Comment: Likely a Gradle thing. Check if adding `testLogging.showStandardStreams = false` solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

Add the -echoOut switch to grails test-app, https://grails.org/wiki/1.2%20Release%20Notes

```
grails test-app -echoOut
```

There are a number of other useful switches on test-app as well, including:

echo System.err messages:

```
grails test-app -echoErr
```

force a clean before running tests (without doing grails clean && grails test-app):

```
grails test-app -clean
```

only run unit tests:

```
grails test-app unit:
```

only run integration tests:

```
grails test-app integration:
```

run in a particular environment:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=production test-app
```

run tests only for a particular test class (like com.foo.MyControllerTests), be sure to leave off the "Tests" suffix

```
grails test-app com.foo.MyController
```

rerun only the tests that failed the last time you ran your tests

[grails test-app to output to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217873/grails-test-app-to-output-to-console)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change the behavior, the -echoOut flag sends the log output to stdout but not to the test reports.  What I'm looking for is to have the log messages logged to the test reports instead of to stdout, which was the default behavior in 2.2 and below.